# Invalid block tag on line 10: 'endblock', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag? django (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-templates

I want registration and log in form in same page and in same html file. when i render form1 i have problem. i search in google but can't fix. can i render two form same html?

this is code --->

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css?{% now "U" %}" />

{% block content %}
    <form action = '' method="post" novalidate="novalidate" id="reg" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="continer">
        {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}
        {{ field.errors }}
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" name="register" id="btn" >registraton</button>
        <button type="button" name="log" id="lgn">login</button>

        </div>

    </form>

    <form action="" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" id="log">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="continer2">
            {% for field in form1 %}
            {{ field }}
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `endfor` for the last `for` loop:

```
        {% for field in form1 %}
        {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
```

The error message indicated that you might be missing an endwith or endfor which is a hint to look for a `with` or `for` that hasn't been closed.